# What are common datasets used for collaboration recommendations?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I look for datasets that I can use for collaboration recommendation (i.e. co-authorship prediction). In other words, the dataset includes details related to authors and their publications.

I am wondering if there are any public datasets in this task or any state-of-the-art datasets? If so, what are they?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.